# How to read a bar chart in openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bar-chart, openpyxl

I have an excel file that has a Bar Chart (Chart2) as a sheet named 'Output'. So I want to change the style format of Chart2 by using Openpyxl. However, I tried the simple code that did not work for me:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Series, Reference

wb = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\sma.xlsx')
sheet1 = wb['Output']
Chart2 = BarChart()
print(Chart2)
Chart2.style = 6
wb.save(r'r'C:\Users\sma.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Can anyone give me the right approach to get my proper result?

Comment: From [the docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html): *"openpyxl does currently not read all possible items in an Excel file so images and charts will be lost from existing files if they are opened and saved with the same name."*

Comment: You have to find the chart in the relevant worksheet and edit it.

Comment: @Tomerikoo.. any other approach to do that and solve my problem

Comment: @CharlieClark..I am trying to same thing but I could not get the proper result. Can you help me out.